# Text mining : Bad predictions of toxic comments using Word2Vec

Tags: pyspark, text-mining, random-forest, word2vec, spacy

I have a dataset containing sentences and boolean columns (0 or 1) to classify the type of the comment (toxic|severe_toxic|obscene|threat|insult|identity_hate).
You can download the dataset here : https://ufile.io/nqns7

I filtered the words with spacy to only keep useful words, i kept : Adjectives, Adverbs, Verbs and Nouns using this function :

```
def filter_words(words) : 
vec = []    
conditions = ('ADV','NOUN','ADJ','VERB')
for token in nlp(words):
    if not token.is_stop and token.pos_ in conditions:
        vec.append(token.lemma_)
return vec
```

Then i converted the dataframe to a parquet file to speed up the performances.

I ended up with a dataframe which looks like this : 
[image]

I used a Word2Vec on this DF to create a features column in order to use RandomForestClassifier to predict if model works well.

Here is the code :

```
    from pyspark.ml.feature import Word2Vec
    from pyspark.sql.functions import *

    word2vec = Word2Vec(inputCol="vector_words",outputCol="features")
    model = word2vec.fit(sentences)
    result = model.transform(sentences)
    result = result.withColumn("toxic", result["toxic"].cast(IntegerType()))

      rf =RandomForestClassifier(labelCol="toxic",featuresCol="features")

      result = result.dropna()
      (trainingSet, testSet) = result.randomSplit([0.7,0.3])

      model_toxic = rf.fit(trainingSet)
      predictions = model_toxic.transform(testSet)
```

But the problem i have here, is that i only have 16 predictions that are considered toxic from which 13 are really identified as toxic while there are about 4000 toxic comments in the set.
I don't understand why. Is it because of the filter i applied on the words, which might be too restrictive( i don't know why though ) or is it because the parameters of my Word2Vec and RandomForestClassifier aren't precise enough?
I'm new to pyspark and i couldn't find any information about bad models, basically people on internet are pretty happy about the results. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I ran your code applying some modifications and it shows 934 correct positive predictions. Basically, I relaxed the conditions for the tokenization of the comments (I can share the code if you are interested), apart from that I cannot see the reason why you are not obtaining satisfactory results. Something it caught my attention is the format of your column `vector_words`, it is an array of an array, have you tried to remove the array that is acting as a wrapper?

Comment: I just recomposed it and the results were the same. Though, whenI loosened up the conditions of tokenization as you did, i obtained better results. But because i use spacy, it takes a lot of time ( about an hour each time ), is there a way to do this without wasting a lot of time?

Comment: I do not use spacy, so I do not really know how to improve the performance. However, on my approach the average length of the array containing the tokenized text is 61, do you have a similar value on your approach?